# Prove $R$ is an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

**Problem:** Let $A = \lbrace1,2,3,4,5,6\rbrace$ and $B = \lbrace2,4,6\rbrace$. The relation $R$ on $\mathcal{P}(A)$ defined by $\forall x,y \in \mathcal{P}(A), xRy \Longleftrightarrow x-B = y-B$

Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation

⠀

Does this imply that $X$ and $Y$ will essentially have to be the same set?

I'm mostly confused by how to visualize $xRy \Longleftrightarrow X-B = Y-B$. I read it as $x$ is only related to $y$ iff the set $X - B$ equals to $Y - B$

Comment: What are 'X' and 'Y'?

Comment: You should use consistent capitalization .Use either $x,y$ everywhere or $X,Y$ everywhere.

Comment: From my notes I have $X-B$, which I thought implied $X$ was a set (that contained $x$). Then should it be instead $x-B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct.  An example of to unequal, but $R$-equivalent sets $x, y$ in ${\cal P}(A)$ is:
$$
x = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}, \quad y = \{1, 3, 4, 6\}.
$$
For visualization, it is helpful to give the following definition of $R$, equivalent to the one above:
$$
x \cap (B^c) = y \cap (B^c).
$$
Now,
$$
B^c = A - B = \{1, 3, 5\}.
$$
So, two sets in ${\cal P}(A)$ are $R$-equivalent if and only if they contain the same odd numbers.

Comment: Okay, I see. How does this make it symmetric though? Since, for example, $\mathcal{P}(A)$ contains $\lbrace1,2\rbrace$ but not $\lbrace2,1\rbrace$. Or would $(x,y)$ be the set that is considered symmetric?

Comment: The elements of a set have no intrinsic order.  The sets $\{1, 2\}$ and ${\2, 1\}$ are one and the same set, because each is a subset of the other.